# Loop to search and print unique value from range

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I have a list of values, and in a table, I have those same values spread out.

I need some sort of loop that can search the 1x20 list and print the first value that is not already in the table, without having to write numerous countif() statements. Is there a way to do this faster?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you need a loop of a range of cells and test if value exists. You'd need to post more of your code to give a specific example but this should get you started:

```
Sub LoopExampleUsingRange()

Dim aCell As Range
For Each aCell In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A20").Cells

If InStr(1, "SOME TEXT/table/OR A CELL VALUE TO S", aCell.Value) Then
    'if it exists put here
    'Perhaps do nothing?

Else
    'if doesn't exist put some code here.

End If


Next aCell

End Sub
```